# Recursively Traversing Ragged JSON Hierarchy in Python 3 to perform a partial leaf node deletion

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, recursive-datastructures

So, I have a JSON block that looks kinda like this:

```
[
{
    "children": [
        {
            "address": "123 Main Street",
            "class": "blarg",
            "children": [
                {
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "y_type": "string",
                                    "x_type": "002",
                                    "002_id": 2222,
                                    "updated_at": "2018-03-29T13:47:42.986Z",
                                    "field020": "AAA",
                                    "field030": "DDD"
                                },
                                {
                                    "y_type": "bool",
                                    "x_type": "007",
                                    "007_id": 2222,
                                    "updated_at": "2018-03-29T13:47:42.986Z",
                                    "field1": True,
                                    "field2": True
                                }
                            ],
                            "create_at": "2018-03-29T13:45:20.875Z",
                            "x_id": "3e0e1b44-ac0d-4bf7-985e-11d74b8be323",
                            "junk_field": {},
                            "x_type": "000",
                            "timezone": "America/New_York",
                            "update_at": "2018-03-29T13:45:20.875Z"
                        },
                        {
                            "sibling": [1,2,3]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

What I need to do is find "children" leaf nodes that are of x_type "007" and delete the field 1 entry associated with that block of data.  I'm having trouble trying to isolate the entire dict associated with only the correct kind of leaf node (children, not sibling) so that I can check it for the correct x_type and do the delete.

I'm not sure what kind of values to pass to/back from the recursive function I've sorta cobbled together.  I've never done recursion in Python before, much less against ragged hierarchy JSON, so I could use some help/guidance on what approaches to use/google for.  I'd appreciate any help you could give to get me goin' in the right direction!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dictionary unpacking with recursion:

```
def d_filter(d):
  return {**({a:b for a, b in d.items() if d.get('x_type') != '007' or a != 'field1'}), \
   'children':list(map(d_filter, d.get('children', [])))} 

new_data = list(map(d_filter, data))
```

---

```
import json
print(json.dumps(new_data, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "children": [
        {
            "address": "123 Main Street",
            "class": "blarg",
            "children": [
                {
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "y_type": "string",
                                    "x_type": "002",
                                    "002_id": 2222,
                                    "updated_at": "2018-03-29T13:47:42.986Z",
                                    "field020": "AAA",
                                    "field030": "DDD",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "y_type": "bool",
                                    "x_type": "007",
                                    "007_id": 2222,
                                    "updated_at": "2018-03-29T13:47:42.986Z",
                                    "field2": true,
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ],
                            "create_at": "2018-03-29T13:45:20.875Z",
                            "x_id": "3e0e1b44-ac0d-4bf7-985e-11d74b8be323",
                            "junk_field": {},
                            "x_type": "000",
                            "timezone": "America/New_York",
                            "update_at": "2018-03-29T13:45:20.875Z"
                        },
                        {
                            "sibling": [
                                1,
                                2,
                                3
                            ],
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
     ]
   }
]
```

Comment: That got me on the right track.  TYVM!!  I appreciate you taking the time to answer this!!  You just saved me from having to explain to my boss why this was gonna be late...

Comment: @Squish88 Glad to help!